# Project folder structure: are makefiles source code too?

Tags: version-control, makefile

I have a large project that is rather heterogenous - different languages and compilers are involved, altogether producing a build with the help of GNU make.

The project folder structure includes:

```
project
   src
      haxe          --Haxe source code
      graphics      --Embeddable graphic resources
      locale        --Locale-specific resources
         chinese    --Chinese language resources
         english    --Generic English resources
   build
      china         --Chinese market
         debug      --Debugging/Testing for developer(s)
         release    --Release
      europe        --European market
         debug      -- ...
         release    -- ...
```

All builds are produced by setting up and running 'make'. What I can't decide on is whether these makefiles should be put in 'src' directory as well? I generally consider original material I write by hand to be source code (since by my line of thought it originated from me and not produced by any program from some other input.) and I DO write my makefiles by hand. Another reason I consider this is because ONLY 'src' directory is a Git repository - I don't really need to version track anything else. Do I put all Makefiles into 'src'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's currently in your `build` directory structure?  Is that the compiled output?

Intuitively (and I may be coming from a very different development world than you, so "intuitively" is a relative term) when I see a `build` folder adjoining a `src` folder, I expect the program's source code to be in the latter and the scripts/tools/etc. needed to build it to be in the former.  The scripts (makefiles in this case, though potentially also to include other things) are themselves source code, as you state, but aren't the program's source.  The distinction is that one is "what is being built" and the other is "how to build it."

If I understand you correctly, `src` is what's bound to your source control and `build` isn't?  Under that circumstance, I would probably create a `build` (or `builder` or `building` or something of that nature) under `src` to house the scripts.  It may be slightly unintuitive that it has to climb another folder before producing its output, but it should sit nicely alongside the resource folders you have there already.

Comment: The `build` directory houses machine-produced content that is generated from source code - this will be binaries, libraries, runtime assets - anything that ends up at a customer's. Indeed, the `src` contains the program's source code, and `build` contains also Makefiles that `make` uses to generate contents of that directory. `src` is bound to source control system (git), nothing else is.  However, I was wondering whether Makefiles would also be source-code since much of my Makefiles is written by hand and includes a lot of information that is vital to a successful build.

Comment: @amn: so your makefiles are not currently under source control?

Comment: @Tom no they're not. Which is part of the reason I am contemplating moving them. I don't think anything but source code needs version control either. And my makefiles grow more and more complex as the project grows and contain valuable information. For instance I am building an Adobe Flash SWF file from an entire directory of source code. However, the SWF dimensions (width, height, framerate) are specified as command line options to the compiler, and so are not part of the source code, while arguably they also make up the project, don't they now?

Comment: Build scripts absolutely, definitely, unarguably belong under source control. If you think only source code belongs under source control, then build scripts must be source code. As for where they go in the project hierarchy, that's a matter of convention and preference, and I don't know enough about Make conventions to make a suggestion. FWIW, in java, I usually have a bin or scripts directory next to the src directory.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to create a Makefile outside your src/ directory, which builds your project and within that src/ directory, another Makefile builds individual modules. That said, I think in your case it is sufficient to keep your Makefile solely in src/ though. I'm not sure if this applies, but you might want to look at the GNU autoconf package, it's used for exactly this type of thing.